# 'Jump to' text box that is off the screen

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, controls

I have an Excel worksheet that has a good number of rows - so it's pretty long. There are text boxes and buttons scattered throughout.

I set the tab order and that works, except for one problem. If the next button or text box is off the screen, the user must scroll to it and then click on it.

I've tried .activate, .setfocus, .select, everything I can think of on tab events, keydown events, even clicking.

How do I "jump to" a control that is off screen?

Comment: You have repeated your last paragraph. Could you instead share something useful? How do you think this should work? Run a macro that will detect a 'visible' text box and then scroll to or select the next one (e.g. by its Index)? Is there a logic by which the text boxes are *scattered* e.g. in column `B` starting with cell `B3` (`.TopLeftCell`) every `40` rows each?

Comment: Have you tried [`ActiveWindow.ScrollRow`](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/scroll/)?

Comment: How did you **set the tab order*?  Like this: [How to set tab order to textboxes in Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4902-excel-textbox-tab-order.html)?

Comment: @TinMan: Yes, exactly that way.

Comment: @PeterT: Yes. And Yes. I just never thought, as Cameron pointed out below, of combining your idea with VBasic2008's. Thank you both!

Comment: @VBasic2008: Yes. And Yes. I just never thought, as Cameron pointed out below, of combining your idea with PeterT's. Thank you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *THINK* what you're asking is how to scroll your rows and columns to focus in on a shape. This can be done.
If, however, you're looking to move a shape to where the user is, just basically follow the steps backwards.
On the other hand, if I've missed the point of this exercise entirely, my apologies.

I'm starting with this shape far off screen:
I've named it "StarHead" because I found it amusing.
[image]

If we're set at cell "A1",
[image]

We can arrive at the shape like so:
[image]

if we run:

```
Sub ScrollToObject()
    
    Dim StarHead As Object
    Dim TLCell As Range
    
    Set StarHead = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Starhead")
    Set TLCell = StarHead.TopLeftCell
    
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = TLCell.Row - 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = TLCell.Column - 3
    
End Sub
```

> ---

As a further bit of fun, I wrote a bit of code to loop trough every shape on a sheet.
Kind of ugly, but it works. If it's something you want to use, it would be easy to clean up.

```
Sub ScrollToNextObject()
    
    Dim MyShape As Object
    Dim TLCell As Range
    Dim SHIndex As Long
    
    Dim SHP As Object
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim CNT As Long
    Dim N As Byte
    Dim I As Long
    
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        SHIndex = 1
        Set MyShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(SHIndex)
    Else
        Set Dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
        I = 0
        For N = 1 To 2
            For Each SHP In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                I = I + 1
                Debug.Print SHP.ID
                If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name).ID = SHP.ID Then CNT = I - 1
                Dict.Add I, SHP.ID
            Next SHP
        Next N
        
        For Each SHP In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If Dict(CNT) = SHP.ID Then
                Set MyShape = SHP
            End If
        Next SHP
        
        Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name).ID
        SHIndex = Dict(CNT)
        
    End If
    
    Set TLCell = MyShape.TopLeftCell
    
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = TLCell.Row
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = TLCell.Column
    MyShape.Select

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the extra bit of code, too! It looks....interesting. I understand what you're doing there, but I've never encountered "byte" as a variable. I think some research is now in order!

Comment: Thank you Cameron! This is _exactly_ what I was asking! Apparently I just didn't know what to even call it - this is so cool!

Comment: Yeah a Byte is like a really small integer (0 to 255). It only takes up 1 byte. Integer, Long and LongLong are other examples of integers (2, 4 and 8 bytes). Because `N` would only ever be 1 or 2, I was safe to only allocate 1 byte of memory. [Here is a breakdown of datatypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)